# How to protect against an image sent in a Rest API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest

I am about to embark on creating a rest api that accepts two images base 64 encoded from an external party.

I have heard from people that it would be prudent to think about protecting against a malicious file being sent to me via some sort of an attack.

My initial thoughts are that I need to think about virus scanning but also an incorrect or dodgy image (for example in image from a porn site).

We are using AWS as our cloud platform. Can anyone help me with some ideas as to best practices / how i can protect against this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general (there are obviously exceptions), if you are just receiving and storing images into something such as S3, you do not need to worry about viruses and whatnot from the image upload, as these files are not going to be executed, and should only be rendered as jpg/png/whatever file format you use.

If you wish to check for unsafe or inappropriate images, you could utilize [Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/)'s Unsafe content detection feature. In addition you could also use Rekognition to perform image tagging and generate metadata for each image.